# Ignore new lines in ansible regular expressions

Tags: regex, ansible

I'm working on a Ansible playbook to extract some information from a file.

The file look like this:

```
[Java,<event_type>]
java    critical 1-
*ARGS <node_name> <server_name>
[Java,<event_type>]
java    critical 1-
*ARGS <node_name> <server_name>
```

Initially and for testing, instead of reading the file I made a variable with breakline to mimic the file.
Now I'm trying test the regular expression using the file, but it doesn't like the \n.

This is the code:

```
- name: Load data from ps_mon.cfg
  slurp:
    src: "{{ PSMON }}"
  register: slurped_user_data

- name: Decode data and store as fact
  set_fact:
    psmon_var: "{{ slurped_user_data.content | b64decode }}"

- set_fact:
    my_var: "{{ psmon_var | regex_search('\\[[J|j]ava(.*)(?=\\[)', multiline=True)}}"
```

The output from the regular expression is this:

```
ok: [test_server] => {
    "my_var": ""
}
```

Basically, the regex_search is not able to find the [ to match the regular expression in the file.
I tried different options to ignore the breakline ((?:\n.*?)*) and [\s\S]*, but they didn't work.

I have two questions:

- What should I change from the regular expression to ignore the breakline?
- How can I match the end of the file in case there is no other [ to match the regular expression?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
Sorry, I forgot to add this.
What I need to extract from the file is:

```
[Java,<event_type>]
java    critical 1-
*ARGS <node_name> <server_name>
```

In the example there are 2 sets, because it may repeat on the file. But the idea is to rerun that part of the playbook as many time as necessary to extract all.

Comment: what's the expected output from this?

Comment: Just added. Sorry, I forgot to add it the first time

Comment: What about `(?s)\[[Jj]ava.*(?=\[)`? `(.|\s)*` is ugly and too slow. You need no `multiline=True` here if it only affects anchors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`\[(?:J|j)ava(.|\s)*(?=\[)`

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ewAe4K/1)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to extract this:
[Java,<event_type>]
java    critical 1-
*ARGS <node_name> <server_name>
[
without the last [

Comment: @radicaled I updated my answer, Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Nop, it didn't like it. The same "my_var": "" result. I will try to change the way I read the file.

Comment: Try this: `\[(?:J|j)ava(.|\s)*(?=\[)`